# moving object at the same time in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("class").click(function() {
    $(".first").animate({
      left: '250px'
    });
  });

  $(".third").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate().css({
      backgroundColor: '#FFF552'
    });
  })

  $(".first").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      width: 300
    })
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first" style="background:#DC143C;"></div><br>
<div class="second" style="background:#CD5C5C;"></div><br>
<div class="third" style="background:#FF69B4;"></div><br>
<div class="fourth" style="background:#FF7F50;"></div>
```

This application works properly. But I need moving all four object at the same time. I have no idea how to do it. Does someone has an idea and can help me?

Comment: moving element onload or on click ?

Comment: onload... when I open the browser I need to see all four object moving on the screen

Comment: `$("class")` is selecting nothing at all

Comment: How do you mean that? It is working fine. I need to move all four div on the page. Do you know how I can make it?